# jquery validation denomination of price

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I am using jquery validation. I need an input field to be number and Denominations of $250 only. The code i have for validation is

```
  rules: {
      myPrice: {
          required: true,
          number: true
      }
```

Now I need it be only denominations of $250. ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a new custom method to check if your price is in denomination of 250,hence simply add a new method using `$.validator.addMethod`

```
 $.validator.addMethod('denominationCheck', function (value) {
        return Number(value) % 250 == 0;
    }, '');
```

And in your rules modify as below

```
rules: {
  myPrice: {
      required: true,
      number: true,
      denominationCheck : 0
  }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Change that semi-colon after `required: true` to a comma and you've got my vote :)

Answer (score 1):

$.validator.addMethod is what you're looking for